# Writing a Gaussian Radial Basis Function in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, gaussian

How could I start to write a Gaussian Radial Basis Function in Mathematica? Please provide coding as references if possible. I have already tried but I still could not run it. Please show some guide to help me run it.

Comment: Show what you have tried.  Also provide some context on how you intend to use it.  There may be a better way than rolling your own function.

Answer (score 2):

Without more details, it's impossible to give any better answer than this.

```
GaussionRadialBasis[x_Real, parameter_Real:1] := Exp[-parameter*x^2];
```